# PayPal Rest API payment with custom invoice number for intended purpose in bank transaction

Tags: rest, paypal, payment, invoice

Edit FYI: Do not use the PayPal REST API if you plan to do something enterprise like. This could lead into a lot of wasted time.
As PayPal mentioned by itself (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#classic-api-questions) the classic API has more features and currently there is no end of life planned.

---

I need to implement a paypal transaction with the new API. Everything is working fine except one thing:

In the classic API I could set a invoice number to reference my custom shop number. When paypal is sending the money to the bank it the transaction has a intended purpose, the given invoice number.

Nowadays with the rest api the intended purpose field is empty. I don't find any hook how to give this invoice number.

For example use this website from paypal: https://devtools-paypal.com/hateoas/index.html?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox#

I create a payment like this:

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "110.54"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://www.ebay.com",
        "cancel_url": "http://www.milo.com"
    }
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "110.54"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
            "my_custom_transaction_id" : "shop_transaction_no_234"
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "return_url",
        "cancel_url": "cancel_url"
    }
}
```

Comment: After talking with paypal technical support: I should NOT use the rest API -,.- Thanks, documentation page for this warnings.... Time to rollback

Comment: how they explain their answer? Why you should not use the Rest API?

Comment: @antongorodezkiy: They said rest api has a beta state. Not every functionality of classic api already is implemented yet. So if you use rest API it may happen you can't do something working with classic. Something essential like the invoice id to identify the payment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this :

**Create Payment :**

```
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$customvalue = 'shop_transaction_no_234';

$transaction = new Transaction();

$transaction->setCustom($customvalue);
```

After the payment process, the response would be like this :

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "110.54"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
            "custom" : "shop_transaction_no_234"
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "return_url",
        "cancel_url": "cancel_url"
    }
}
```

Additional note, if you want to get the transaction details of from the paypal response, here's how I did it

```
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
/**
 * Get Ids from url
 */
$paymentId  = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerId    = $_GET['PayerID'];

/**
 * Get payment details and assign to object
 */
$payment    = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
$obj        = json_decode($payment);

/**
 * this script returns the custom value you assigned
 */
$custom     = $obj->transactions[0]->custom;
```

And That's It! Hopefully this would be useful for all :)

Comment: Time pasts and API changes. Nowadays paypal's transaction object has more fields. Your "custom", which is not exactly what I was looking for. I didn't test it, but I think it is strongly recommended to use invoice_number to store custom shop's invoice number to track back your transaction. But thanks!